# How to pass custom data to EDataTables in Yii

Tags: php, yii, cgridview, edatatables

I am using Yii EDataTables Extension : http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/edatatables/

I have Widget of EDataTables as follow

```
$this->createWidget(
    'ext.EDataTables.EDataTables', array(
        'id'           => 'items',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'ajaxUrl'      => '/ajax-update',
        'columns'      => array(array(
                                'user_id',
                                'email',
                                'name',
                                'created_at:date:Updated',
                                'updated_at:date:Updated',
                                )
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'bStateSave'    => false,
            'bPaginate'     => true,
        ),
    )
);
```

I want to pass custom ( value,array or object to the widget so i can use it in the row value )

I have looked around many places but i couldn't find way to do it.
Could you please advice how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have custom column Value for name for example :

> $nameExp = '$this->grid->options["nameArray"][$data->user_id]';

And Array like this

```
$namesInArray = array(
                '1'=>'FirstName LastName 1',
                '2'=>'FirstName LastName 2',
                '3'=>'FirstName LastName 3',
                '4'=>'FirstName LastName 4',
            );
```

The possible way to pass extra data not from data provide is to send it with options or htmloptions array ( because all other params for the widget has to have an attribute in the class referring to )

So You can pass the object or the array in the options array and use it as below

```
$nameExp = '$this->grid->options["nameArray"][$data->user_id]';
$namesInArray = array(
    '1'=>'FirstName LastName 1',
    '2'=>'FirstName LastName 2',
    '3'=>'FirstName LastName 3',
    '4'=>'FirstName LastName 4',
);
$this->createWidget(
    'ext.EDataTables.EDataTables', array(
        'id'           => 'items',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'ajaxUrl'      => '/ajax-update',
        'columns'      => array(array(
                                    'user_id',
                                    'email',
                                    'name',
                                    array('class' => 'CDataColumn', 'name' => 'Name from array options', 'sortable' => false, 'value' => $nameExp, 'type' => 'raw'),
                                    'created_at:date:Updated',
                                    'updated_at:date:Updated',
                                )
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'bStateSave'    => false,
            'bPaginate'     => true,
            'nameArray'     => $namesInArray
        ),
    )
);
```

You will be able to use/access the Array, value or the object with that row value expression and do the logic you need there !